# Aho-Corasick text matching on groups of patterns

Tags: aho-corasick

Aho-Corasick algorithm has solved multi-pattern matching perfectly, here is my question:

There are several groups of words: `['hello', 'world'], ['foo', 'bar']`, the text is `'I come to the world and say hello to everyone'`.

Because both `hello` and `world` are in the text, we can say the pattern `['hello', 'world']` is matched regardless of the sequence but `['foo', 'bar']` is not.

Is there a Aho-Corasick based algorithm which can solve the problem?

Comment: have you found a solution? I the exact same question. Using [pyahocorasick](https://pyahocorasick.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package for python